# If $\varphi\colon X\to Y$ is a dominant morphism of affine varieties, $X$ irreducible, then $\varphi X$ contains nonempty open of closure.

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

There is a well known theorem that if $\varphi\colon X\to Y$ is a dominant map of affine varieties, and $X$ is irreducible, then $\varphi X$ contains a nonempty open set over $\overline{\varphi X}$.

Since $\varphi$ is dominant, $\varphi^\ast\colon k[Y]\to k[X]$ is injective, and $k[X]$ is an integral domain since $X$ is irreducible. There's a theorem from commutative algebra that says there is an $a\neq 0\in k[Y]$ such that if $f\colon k[Y]\to k$ is such that $f(a)\neq 0$, then $f$ extends to a morphism $\bar{f}\colon k[X]\to k$.

In particular, if $D(a)$ is a principal open in $Y$ for $a\in k[Y]$, then for any $y\in D(a)$, $ev_y(a)=a(y)\neq 0$, so $ev_y\colon k[Y]\to k$ extends to a morphism $k[X]\to k$. The [notes](http://pages.uoregon.edu/brundan/math681fall07/notes2.pdf) I'm reading here at the very end say this means $ev_y=ev_x\circ\varphi^\ast$ for some $x\in X$. But I don't see how knowing an extension of $ev_y$ exists gives this equality.

Comment: Any morphism of $k$-algebras $k[X]\to k$ must be of the form $ev_x$ for some $x\in X$. Indeed, suppose that $k[X]=k[x_1,\dots,x_n]/I$ for some ideal $I$: then a map $g\colon k[X]\to k$ corresponds to choosing $a_i=g(x_i)$ and then this morphism becomes the evaluation in $(a_i,\dots,a_n)$